# Why is it that there is this error "undefined name 'gini' " in this code?

Tags: python

[image: This is the snippet of the code where the error occurs] I can't seem to figure out why there is an error. I am learning decision tree algorithm.

```
def gini(rows):
    """calculate the gini impurity for a list of rows."""
    
    counts = class_counts(rows)
    impurity  = 1
    for lbl in counts:
        prob_of_lbl = counts[lbl] / float(len(rows))
        impurity -= prob_of_lbl**2
    return impurity

def info_gain(left, right, current_uncertainty):
    """Information Gain"""
    
    #The uncertainty of the starting node, minus the weighted
    #impurity of two child nodes.
    
    p = float(len(left)) / (len(left) + len(right))
    return current_uncertainty - p * gini(left) - (1 - p) * gini(right)
```

Comment: return current_uncertainty - p * gini(left) - (1 - p) * gini(right)
this is where the error occurs

Comment: There is no problem in _this_ code - beside you not showing how to call it and missing other things.  Check your indentations, check that gini() occures before info_gain(), check that you haven't got giní or gìnì instead. Check out how name scoping works in python

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: Usually class methods got `self` as first param if they belong to the classes instance, else they can be marked `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` - but then you still need to tell python which class they reside in:  `MyClass.Whatever(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an indentation before the `def gini ...` ? If your `gini` function is in a class you should use `ClassName.gini`.

For example:

```py
class ClassName:
    def gini(rows):
        ...
    def info_gain(left, right, current_uncertainty):
        ...
        ClassName.gini(rows)
        ...
```

Comment: `self` ?  `@staticmethod`. `@classmethod`, ... ?